# Majorate a function by an integrable function

Tags: measure-theory

I want to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\frac{1+n x}{(1+x)^{n}}$ therefore I have to use one of the following theorem: Dominated Convergence Theorem or Monotone Convergence Theorem.

I wanted to majorate $\phi_n(x) = \frac{1+n x}{(1+x)^{n}}$ by a integrable function on $\mathbb{R}_+$, because the sequence $\left(\phi_n\right)_n$ is a descending sequence and $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \phi_0(x) dx$ is not finite, cause $\phi_0(x) = 1$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} 1 dx = \infty$.

Thus I have to use the DCT and therefore I still have to majorate $\phi_n(x)$ by a integrable function on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type of integral that you can actually compute directly:
$$
\frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n} =\frac{1-n}{(1+x)^n} +\frac{n}{(1+x)^{n-1}}
$$

Hence , for $n>2$

\begin{align}
I_n&=\int^\infty_0\frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n}\,dx =(1-n)\int^\infty_0(1+x)^{-n}\,dx+n\int^\infty_0(1+x)^{-(n-1)}\,dx\\
&=(1+x)^{-(n-1)}|^\infty_0+\frac{n}{2-n}(1+x)^{2-n}|^\infty_0\\
&=-1+\frac{n}{n-2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
\end{align}

If you insists in using dominated convergence to estimate the limit of $I_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ you may try the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n}&=\frac{(1+nx)(1+x^2)}{(1+x)^n(1+x^2)}\\
&=\frac{1+nx +x^2+nx^3}{(1+x)^n}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
&\leq \frac{1+nx+\tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+\tfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3}{(1+x)^n}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{align}
which holds for say $n\geq 4$